# Specifying class type in nested config sections in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, dependency-injection, app-config

I've been going through all the documentation I can find for ConfigurationSection and ConfigurationElement trying to figure out how to nest without contaminating my classes with a ton of XML parsing - and just can't seem to find anything.

There's some additional refactoring that needs to be done so I can inject more of the dependencies - but this should give you enough to understand what I'm trying to do and maybe point me in the right direction:

```
Dim mediInfo = New MeditechInfo
    With mediInfo
        .ADMDb = My.Settings.MeditechADM
        .Directory = My.Settings.MeditechDirectory
        .MIS = My.Settings.MeditechMIS
        .Segment = My.Settings.MeditechSeg
        .MeditechPort = My.Settings.MeditechPort
        .MeditechIP = My.Settings.MeditechIP
    End With


    Monitor = New Monitor(Of PageAction)(New MeditechOutbound(mediInfo, New HCIFileStore))
```

MeditechOutbound and HCIFileStore are both implementations of interfaces.

```
Public Class Monitor(Of TDocModel)
Public Property Outbound As IHISOutbound(Of TDocModel)

…
Public Class MeditechOutbound
Implements IHISOutbound(Of PageAction)

Public Property MeditechInfo As MeditechInfo
Public Property Store As IFileStore
```

What I'm trying to get to is configuration that looks something like this:

```
 <Monitor of="PageAction">
     <Outbound type="assembly.namespace.MeditechOutbound">
            <MeditechInfo type="...MeditechInfo" MeditechIP="127.0.0.1"..../>
     </Outbound>
     <Store type="...HCIFileStore"/>
</Monitor>
```

I don't really have any way to assure that going forward, any other implementations of say IHISOutbound are going to have exactly two constructor parameters, etc - so I can't just write one configSection and make assumptions - where do I start here?